# "worksheet.write" ı can not write excel

Tags: python-3.x, excel, xlsxwriter

**PROBLEM:I can not write excel**

My work with python 3.5 does not work with python 3.8
Unable to write from Python to Excel

I cannot write the data in the lists to excel
thanks for your help

My work with python 3.5 does not work with python 3.8
Unable to write from Python to Excel

I cannot write the data in the lists to excel
thanks for your help
My work with python 3.5 does not work with python 3.8
Unable to write from Python to Excel

I cannot write the data in the lists to excel
thanks for your help

```
scores="C:/Users/palav/OneDrive/Belgeler/bitirme_tezi/ansvers.xlsx"
workbook_ansvers=xlsxwriter.Workbook(scores)
worksheet_ansvers=workbook_ansvers.add_worksheet()
worksheet_ansvers_load=load_workbook(scores)
sheet=worksheet_ansvers_load.active



   #-----------------CEVAPLAR İÇİN EXCEL DOSYASI OLUŞTURMA------------------#    



 def ansver_excel():

        
        #-------BAŞLIK
        array_ansvers_excel_row=[]
        rows=ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=2, max_row=1, max_col=total_columns)
        for row in rows:
            for cell in row:
                array_ansvers_excel_row.append(cell)
        
        
        #------SÜTUN    
        array_ansvers_excel_col=[]
        rows=ws.iter_rows(min_row=1, min_col=1, max_row=total_rows, max_col=1)
        for row in rows:
            for cell in row:
                array_ansvers_excel_col.append(cell)
        #--------------STUDENTS--------------------#
        row_name=0
        col_name=1
        
        for i in range(len(array_ansvers_excel_row)):
            array_ansvers_excel_row_new.append(array_ansvers_excel_row[i].value)
        for i in array_ansvers_excel_row_new:
            worksheet_ansvers.write(row_name, col_name,i)
            col_name+=1
        #-------------------ID---------------------#
        row_name=0
        col_name=0
        
        for i in range(len(array_ansvers_excel_col)):
            array_ansvers_excel_col_new.append(array_ansvers_excel_col[i].value)    
        for i in array_ansvers_excel_col_new:
            worksheet_ansvers.write(row_name, col_name,i)
            row_name+=1
        
        worksheet_ansvers_load.save('ansvers.xlsx')
        
     
        #-----------------------!EXCEL OLUŞTURULDU---------------------#  
    ansver_excel() #TABLOYU OLUŞTURDUM
```